# Where can we rent or buy a tent for Balkan road trip?

Tags: camping, macedonia, balkans

I am planning a road trip through Macedonia, Albania, Montenegro and Kosovo this summer. We will fly into Skopje and get a rental car there. Besides other accommodation, we also want to camp for a couple of days. Since our flights are hand luggage only there is no chance of bringing a tent (or much other equipment) with us.

Are there places where we could rent camping gear? If not, where can we  buy something affordable just for the trip? We basically need a two-person tent plus some sort of mats; we would bring our own sleeping bags.

Answer (score 3):

I'm able to find two outdoor gear stores in Skopje:

- [Scout Outdoor Shop](https://scout.mk/), opening hours Monday - Friday 0830 - 2100, Saturday 1000 - 1800. Located on ulitsa Maksim Gorki Br. 17.
- [Outdoor](http://www.outdoor.mk/), opening hours Monday - Friday 0900 - 2000, Saturday 1000 - 1700. Located on ulitsa Makedonija br. 16.

I haven't visited these stores myself but they seem to carry the necessary gear. I don't know if they have gear for rent.